# Macro that repeats input of items in enumerate environment

Tags: macros, enumerate

My objective is to create Multiple Choice Answer Sheet. I have managed to create the circled letter environment using tikz but my question is that if one can create a macro that will repeat the itemization input `\item abcdtest` as it is the same by looking like `\mcquestion{n}` where n will be the number of MC items that you want.

In short I want to replace:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\end{enumerate}
```

with `\mcquestion{8}` for example.

Here is the sample code I have so far. Any insight into the matter will help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\abcdtest{%
\noindent\lower1.5ex\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    {
    \path (\i cm,0cm) coordinate (C\i);
    \draw (C\i) circle (0.35cm);
    }
\foreach \j/\k in {1/A,2/B,3/C,4/D}
{
\draw (\j cm,0cm) node {\k};
}
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{enumerate}
\item \abcdtest
\item \abcdtest
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\foreach` command you use isn't limited to tikz elements. It can be used anywhere. Adding

```
\newcommand{\mcquestion}[1]{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
    \item \abcdtest
  }
}
```

to your preamble lets you have a document of

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\mcquestion{6}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking about implementing it but rather in the tikz picture and not outside and I was not certain whether it would have worked.

Comment: If you did it in the picture environment, you'd also have to add the numbers. Not sure if that's worthwhile.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Your approach serves me best.